# How mock methods of repository in Service for Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I try to have a unit test for my service, I mocked everything needed, How I can Mock repository methods that Service is calling so that has value and code is not breaking,

This is my unit test:

```
  public async Task Updateuser_ReturnsResponse()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new UpdateUserRequest()
        {
            Guid = new Guid("92296ac1-f8e1-489a-a312-6ea9d31d60f8"),
            FirstName = "TestFirst",
            LastName = "TestLast",
            PhoneWork = "9495467845",
            EmailWork = "test123@yahoo.com",
        };

        var respose = new UpdateUserResponse()
        {
            Success = true
        };

        var getGuidRequest = new GetGuidRequest()
        {
            Guid = request.Guid
        };

        var getGuidResponse = new GetGuidResponse()
        {
            Guid = request.Guid
        };

        var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        var mockAwsProxy = new Mock<IAwsProxy>();

        mockUserRepository.Setup(s => s.UpdateUserAsync(request)).ReturnsAsync(respose);
        mockUserRepository.Setup(i => i.GetGuidAsync(getGuidRequest)).ReturnsAsync(getGuidResponse);
        var sut = new FromService.UserService(....);
        // Act
        var response = await sut.UpdateUserAsync(request);
        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(response);
        Assert.True(response.Success);
    }
```

My problem is  when calling  - var response = await sut.UpdateUserAsync(request); It goese to service and this GuidResponse is empty so it break after as shows GuidResponse Null:

```
    public async Task<UpdateUserResponse> UpdateUserAsync(UpdateUserRequest request)
    {
        if (request.EmailWork.HasValue() || request.Role.HasValue())
        {
            var GuidResponse = await userRepository.GetGuidAsync(new GetGuidRequest
            {
                Guid = request.Guid
            });
            // it breaks here because GuidResponse is Null.
            if (GuidResponse.Guid != null && request.EmailWork.HasValue())
            {
            .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because the setup does not match what was actually given to the mock when the test was exercised.

Use `It.Is<T>()` to match the passed argument parameter

```
//...omitted for brevity

mockUserRepository
    .Setup(_ => _.GetGuidAsync(It.Is<GetGuidRequest>(x => x.Guid == request.Guid)))
    .ReturnsAsync(getGuidResponse);

//...omitted for brevity
```

assuming the mocked repository is what was injected into the SUT

Reference [Moq Quickstart: Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)